# Django Datefield Filter using DateTime field

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a filter in django-admin that displays "date from" and "date to" filter fields. The problem is that the field that is being filtered on "received_date" is a DateTime field whereas the filter fields display dates in the following format '2011-10-01' - this is the intended behaviour, the filter should list all items by date regardless of time. However at the moment it won't list any results because the times are missing. How can I get the filter to work without specifying the times for the dates?

Answer (score 0):

Just construct a new datetime from the given date, and use that for filtering the Queryset. For the "from" (greater or equal) filter hardcode the time to midnight. For the "to" (less or equal) filter hardcode the time to one second before midnight:

```
from datetime import datetime

dt_from = datetime(d_from.year, d_from.month, d_from.day, 0, 0, 0)

dt_to = datetime(d_to.year, d_to.month, d_to.day, 23, 59, 59)
```

(if you're worried about milliseconds, make dt_to "midnight of following day" and do a "less than" filter.)

Comment: ...and you get "following day" by adding a 24h timedelta, no need to worry about last day of the month.